# Access Tomcat via loadbalancer

Tags: tomcat, google-cloud-platform

We facing issue in deployment in GCP

We have created Loadbalancer with HTTPS

And created two instances for front end angular 80 port and back end tomcat 8080 port

Nginix used for angular tomcat used for Java API(SSL decoded in LB)

For eg: Front end accessible via loadbalancer https://exampledomain/screen

But inside front end Screen, Java api is used to get data

Front end screen is accessible via loadbalancer

Problem
In these case how to call the API, any suggestions please it will be helpful

Comment: So, what you are trying to achieve is to have your frontend exposed at "https://exampledomain/screen", which is currently working fine, but want something else like "https://exampledomain/backend" for your tomcat 8080 port ?

How are your backends configured at your Load Balancer level ?

Can you share a screenshot of your load balancer config ? (please omit any identifiable information)

Comment: Why do you need to decode the SSL in the JAVA API part? Is it not too much responsibilities?

Comment: @Frank In loadbalancer we have added the host and path in GCP for calling the services like /screen call angular instance same way for back end call /backend /api call back end ApI instance

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry for the late reply we have a requirement to apply SSL in LB alone, application should work via Loadbalancer  domain(https://exampledomain/screen) both angular and java need to deployed in HTTP could you help us about this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Load balancer you have 2 path rules

1. One for your frontend (in my screenshot, the `cip-bucket`, I serve directly the statics file from a Bucket, not from an expensive instance behind a NGINX proxy). All the url in /screen/* will be redirect to it
2. One for the backend in Java, a NEG or a instance group (even a serverless NEG if you want to deploy to Cloud Run your code for example). Here, it's the default endpoint, all the unmatched requests pattern are routed to it

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply we have applied above but we have instance group for backend so we applied /examplebackend in Loadbalancer but while calling API via loadbalancer is not working https://exampledomain/examplebackend could you help us about this issue

Comment: Can you detail what is not working? Doyou have errors logs? What's the HTTP return code? Can you edit your question with your config and the error details?